# If $f$ is differentiable function on $[0,1]$ , where $f'(0)= 1$ and $f'(1)=0$, prove that there is constant $ c\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=f(c)$.

Tags: calculus

So I should find at least one constant $c$ in $(0,1)$ for which $f'(c)=f(c)$. I think I should use Rolle's theorem here somehow, I am just not quite sure how, I mean if $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ then it is continuous on the same interval, now I have to prove somehow that $f(0)=f(1)$ or I should find another function which would be product of $f(x)$ and another function and which would fit into this requirement. Any ideas?

Comment: You need further conditions, otherwise the conclusion need not hold. Is it perhaps assumed that $f\colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$?

Comment: No. All i have is up there, there's nothing more is assumed.

Comment: Then go and look for a counterexample. Start with choosing a simple $f'$ satisfying the premises.

Comment: I thought about that, f'(x) = 1- x  was the first function i thought of, but what can i do after that?

Comment: That's a good choice. What are the possibilities for $f$ with that choice of $f'$?

Comment: f(x)= x - (x^2)/2 + constant (i found this by integrating f'(x)) but still f(1) is not equal to zero, which is required, i tried to find a function that meets that requirement and that is product of f(x) and another function but i failed to find appropriate one, i tried g(x) = -x/2 + f(x) and both g(1) and g(0) are equal to zero, but i couldn't prove anything with that g(x) after that.

Comment: You didn't state that $f(1) = 0$ was required. That wouldn't change things, however. If you choose the constant so that $f(1) = 0$, then we still have $f(c) < f'(c)$ for all $c\in (0,1)$. If additionally to that you also have a constraint on $f(0)$, _that_ would probably change things.

Comment: So i should find a constant that fits f(1) = 0, constant could be -1/2 since f(x) = x - (x^2)/2 + constant but then f(0) wouldn't be zero so again, i can't use Rolle

Comment: Rolle's theorem has nothing to do with it. Remember, we are looking for a counterexample to the claim.

Comment: But, what will happen after we find a counter example, that would mean that we will find a constant c in (a,b) such that f'(c) is not equal to f(c). How that helps me?

Comment: No, finding a counterexample means that we find an $f$ with $f'(0) = 1, \, f'(1) = 0$ (and maybe $f(1) = 0$ if that is also demanded) such that *there is no* $c\in (0,1)$ *with* $f(c) = f'(c)$. And thus proving the assertion false. I suspect that there are other conditions on $f$ that you have not stated which would make the assertion true.

Comment: Well, i am supposed to prove that it is true, truthfulness of the statement is not in question, i only have to prove that it is true, and if i could find function $g$ which is some combination of $f$ and another function such that $g(1)=g(0)$ then i could use Rolle's theorem to prove the statement. The way i understood what you are trying to say, you are maybe trying to get me to contradiction while trying to find counterexample. There are no other conditions on $f$, i checked again.

Comment: The truthfulness of the statement is indeed not in question. **As written, it is wrong.** Don't try to do the impossible for too long.

Comment: So this is actually false, but how can i prove that?

Comment: By finding a counterexample. Find an $f$ satisfying the stated assumptions, but such that $f(c) \neq f'(c)$ for all $c \in (0,1)$.